# Why isn't the POST in npm-got sending arrays properly when using form?

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests

I wanted to recreate my python requests code in javascript for an API.

Python code:

```
response = requests.post("https://httpbin.org/post",data={
    "test":["hello","world"]
})

print(response.text)
```

which returns:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {
    "test": [
      "hello",
      "world"
    ]
  },
  "headers": { "i removed"},
  "json": null,
  "origin": "i removed",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Then when I try to use npm-got to recreate the same request this happens:

```
const data = await got.post('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    form : {"test":["hello","world"]}
})

console.log(data.body);
```

which returns:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "test": "hello,world"
  }, 
  "headers": {"i removed"}, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "i removed", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Why does the array turn into a string with a comma? How could I make it POST like the python request?

Comment: Try to stringify data with `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried the KY instead that seems to match up better

```
import ky from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/ky?dts';

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('test', 'hello');
formData.append('test', 'world');
const response = await ky.post("https://httpbin.org/anything", {body: formData}).json();
console.log(response);
```

See https://codepen.io/ptahume/pen/poLRJKN

I hope this is of some help

Comment: If you look at the json returned by the python code, it shows that the data was sent as "form" not "json". I want the javascript code to send it as "form" too.

Comment: ah, in that case, I have updated the answer for you and the code pen, that should be what you are after hopefully?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't use ky but using formData in got preserved the array value.

Comment: ah cool, yes I guess you could use it with got too, my bad lol, well glad you worked it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

try adding .json() to then end of the function call

`got.post(...., { test:['hello','world']}).json()`

objects and JSON are not the same in JS, need to convert the object, the npm-got library has a function to do that, or you can use js native JSON class: `data = JSON.stringify({test: ['hello','world']});`